# Advice on python module to connect to ActiveMQ

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I am starting to work on project with ActiveMq and python. I am creating a python client to connect to activemq and send Avro messages. I have now a python script which generates the messages in AVRO with the particular schema i need. Now I am trying to implement a stomp client to conenct to ActiveMQ and send the AVRO encoded messages.

I cannot find any usefull information online and the stomp implementation seems quite complex. Would anyone have any sugestions  on alternative python module that they used to send binary(AVRO) messages to AMQ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There are several STOMP python clients already available, no need to roll your own.  You can find a list on the [STOMP spec site](http://stomp.github.io/implementations.html).  Take a look at the various options and choose one that meets your needs.